# How to achieve this relational model in EF code-first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would really like to use EF for my project but I am having some trouble figuring out how to use the code-first approach if I want to achieve this in the DB:

```
Posts
============================================================================
Id :int | Title :string | Author :string | Date : datetime| Content :string 
============================================================================

Tags
=============
Name :string
=============

PostTags
===============================
Post_Id :int | Tag_Name :string
===============================

ReadBy
===============================
Post_Id :int | Reader_Name :string
===============================
```

Could someone help me out how should I do this using code-first EF ?

I have no idea how to create the `Tags` table, since it only has primitive types, and I'm not sure how to define those M2M mappings for `PostTags` and `ReadBy`.

I know the relational design is pretty simple since it uses mostly primitive data types, and under other circumstances I would have just made my DAL manually, but I would like to use EF code-first since I know I will benefit from it in the future when adding more features to the app.

Thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be my approach to your problem:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Reader> Readers { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Reader
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

End result:
[image]